# Wordpress Gutenberg HTML block restrictions on Ajax requests

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, wordpress-gutenberg

Are there any restrictions on issuing Ajax requests from a Gutenberg html block?

I have an html/jquery script making an Ajax request following wordpress protocol on Ajax but my post request is rejected with a 400 post status.

Comment: no, I'm not sure how a restriction would be implemented or why it would be added, without seeing code or any info about the request it's difficult to tell ( have you considered the far superior REST API endpoints instead? They will tell you what you did wrong in plain english instead of failing mysteriously with a blank `400` response )